# Trying to destructure a value from an object returns an error

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I'm trying to fetch a name property from an object using destructuring but the error returning says 'cannot read property name of undefined.

```
    // Get genres for given movie
    getGenres = (genreIds, genres) => {
        return genreIds.map(genreId => {
            const filteredGenres = genres.filter(genre => genre.id === genreId);
            const { name } = filteredGenres[0];
            return name;
        })
    };
```

If I console log `filteredGenres[0]` I do get a valid object back with a name and id, I've also checked this with `typeof` to ensure. The result is:
`{id: 14, name: "Fantasy"}`

If i try to console log `filteredGenres[0].name` I also get the same cannot read property name of undefined error.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong? Any help is really greatly appreciated! :)

I've created a stackblitz as requested. File in question is `NowPlaying.js`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ow3x3u

Comment: Can you share an example for the arrays?

Comment: Unrelated but you should probably use `.find` instead of `.filter`

Comment: be careful, `filter` returns an empty array if there are not elements which match the condition. In that case, `filteredGenres[0]` is `undefined` and you are destructuring a prop of `undefined`

Comment: Can you post a reproducible sample from something like https://stackblitz.com so we can see everything you're working with?

Comment: if `filteredGenres[0]` is not `undefined` and the `console.log` returns values how is that possible directly after that `filteredGenres[0].name` throws error ?!

Comment: Thank you for replies! I've created a stackblitz as requested... any help is truly appreciated. I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Currently your stackblitz doesn't render anything, so it isn't reproducing the error.

Comment: if this condition `genre.id === genreId` not equal true so the value of `filteredGenres` it will be `undefined`

Comment: you have to use find instead of filter `genres.find(genre => genre.id === genreId)` or use condition before the destructuring `if(!filteredGenres[0]) return false`

Answer (score 1):

As per your Stackblitz sample, the state property `genres` is initialized as an empty array.

This means that when you pass this as a prop to `NowPlaying`, `filterGenres` will also be an empty array and thus the error you get.

This happens only before the *genres* are fetched. **After** `genres` is fetch and the state is updated, the state is updated and everything looks fine.

You have to account for the `genres` array being empty.